# How to sum the value of 2 rows with vlookup by only using 1 formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup, xlookup

Here is what I did

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP(M3,P2:Q23,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(N3,P2:Q23,2,FALSE)
```

I want to sum the values with just one formula and not repeat it

Im using Excel Online

I tried `=XLOOKUP(M2:N2,P3:P23,Q3:Q23)` but I get a value error,does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: It doesnt seems you are using `Excel Online`, it is `Google Sheets`, both differs a lot, confirm what you are using exactly

Comment: Can you describe your objection to the double lookup?  We often end up using a formula that invokes 7 functions calls to obtain the same result, because we didn’t like the looks of two functions calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try in `Excel Online`:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C3`

```
=SUM(SCAN(0,M3:N3,LAMBDA(x,y,VLOOKUP(y,P3:Q12,2,0))))
```

---

Works for me in `Google Sheet` as well

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C3`

```
=SUM(SCAN(0,M3:N3,LAMBDA(x,y,VLOOKUP(y,P3:Q12,2,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if, and only if, you are certain the M2 and N2 will not be the same value:

`=SUMPRODUCT( ( (P2:P23=M2) + (P2:P23=N2) ) * Q2:Q23 )`

If you want N2 = M2 to be valid and result in the number added twice, then:

`=SUMPRODUCT( (P2:P23=M2) * Q2:Q23 ) + SUMPRODUCT( (P2:P23=N2) * Q2:Q23 )`

But then you are back to repeating the formula.

I used M2 and N2 for the lookup values; your post uses row references 2 and 3 sometimes interchangeably.